# Python instalation in openSUSE Leap via terminal

Tags: python, opensuse

I'm new to openSUSE and I want to install the newest python version, via terminal not using the YaST.

I have downloaded the latest python tarball on their website,extracted it and via terminal I entered on the folder. Then I proceeded with "./configure" and got some error.

```
:~/Downloads/Python-3.7.4> ./configure
configure: loading site script /usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for python3.7... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/egydio/Downloads/Python-3.7.4':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Are you using openSUSE Tumbleweed or openSUSE Leap 15.1?

Comment: [Can I ask questions about installation in SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338203/can-i-ask-questions-about-installation-in-so) Software tools commonly used by programmers and is
**a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.**

Answer (score 0):

```
# Tested on OpenSUSE 15.1. Likely to work on many versions of OpenSUSE.
# This is a minimal install.  You can add additional modules to your liking.
sudo zypper in gcc zlib-devel libffi-devel readline-devel
sudo zypper in libopenssl-devel  # Optional. Allows compiling against OpenSSL.
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/Python-3.7.4.tar.xz
unxz Python-3.7.4.tar.xz
tar -xf Python-3.7.4.tar
cd Python-3.7.4
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/lib-dynload/ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload  # This symlink corrects the readline error.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess simply adding `--libdir=<prefix>/lib` to configuration call will solve the problem.